# How to Cast XmlCDataSection to XDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Does anyone know how to cast XmlCDataSection to XDocument in C#?

This is what I have so far but its not working:

```
XmlCDataSection xcData = xcDataInput as XmlCDataSection;

XDocument xdoc = xcData.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(node => XDocument.Parse(node.OuterXml).Root);
```

This is the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: You cannot cast a class to an unrelated type.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear why you're using `Cast` or `Select` at all. I suspect you just want:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xcData.InnerText);
```

Note that I'm using `InnerText` rather than `OuterXml`, as the outer XML of a CDATA node will never be a valid XML document on its own. If this isn't what you're looking for, please show a complete example of a document containing a CDATA section, and the document you want to get out of it.

Comment: Feeding the `OuterXml` of a CDATA section to the `Parse` method of an `XDocument` is not going to work as a complete document can't contain a single CDATA section. `XDocument.Parse(xcData.InnerText)` makes sense if the CDATA contains the markup of an XML document.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can perform the cast you have to tell which element. Select method return a list. You probably want the first item so..

```
XDocument xdoc = xcData.Cast<XmlNode>().First(node =>XDocument.Parse(node.OuterXml).Root);
```